# MySQL Workbench has encountered a problem

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Не получается создать соединение в Workbench, показывает следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но с командной строки спокойно подключаюсь к sql серверу, в IntelIJ тоже могу подключится.

В Configure Server Management выдает такую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сегодня в первый раз установил MySQL и Workbench соответственно, вроде бы делал все по инструкции..

Answer (score 0):

Была таже проблема. Стояла последняя версия MySQL. Поставил более позднюю версию - 5.6.40 - все заработало без проблем